# Unity Cant jump and move on the same time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello and thanks for reading this.

I made a little game in Unity and I finally got the movement controls with touch input to work.

But right now I face a little problem with combining the movement and jumping part. I cant jump if I'm moving BUT I can move if I'm jumping.

Each of my arrow keys contain a script and then later calls the "RobotController" script to start the movement.

ArrowRight and ArrowLeft Script. They look very much alike so I'll only post 1:

```
private RobotController PlayermoveRight;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    PlayermoveRight = GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<RobotController>();
}

void OnMouseOver()
{

    if(Input.touchCount >= 1) 
    { 
        var touchr = Input.touches[0];
        if(touchr.phase != TouchPhase.Ended && touchr.phase != TouchPhase.Canceled)
        {
            PlayermoveRight.MoveRight();
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
}
```

The ArrowUp script:

```
void OnMouseOver()
{
    GameObject Go = GameObject.Find("Player");
    if ((Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began) || (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))) 
    {
        Go.GetComponent<RobotController>().Jump();
    }
}
```

And the RobotController script:

```
public double moveTime = 0.1;
public double moveTimeR = 0.1;
private double lastPressedTime = 0.0;
private double PressRight = 0.0;

public void MoveLeft() // If ArrowLeft is clicked or Pressed
{
    lastPressedTime = Time.timeSinceLevelLoad; 
}

public void MoveRight() // If ArrowRight is clicked or Pressed
{
    PressRight = Time.timeSinceLevelLoad;
}



void FixedUpdate () {


    if (PressRight + moveTimeR > Time.timeSinceLevelLoad) 
    {
        rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2 (maxSpeed, rigidbody2D.velocity.y);
    } 
    else if (lastPressedTime + moveTime > Time.timeSinceLevelLoad) 
    {
        rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2 (maxSpeed - maxSpeed - maxSpeed, rigidbody2D.velocity.y);

    }
    else 
    {
        rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(0.0f, rigidbody2D.velocity.y);
    }

}

public void Jump()
{
    if (isOnGround == true) {
        anim.SetBool("Ground",false);
        rigidbody2D.AddForce (new Vector2 (0, jumpForce));
    }
}
```

How can I do so I can jump and move on the same time.?

Comment: I'm not an Unity developer, so just a question: are you sure the device you are using accepts multiple touch inputs at the same time?

Comment: I tried on 3 devices and they should all be able to accept multi touch input.

Comment: Because your move sets velocity to a `new Vector2` it will over rule the jumps added force. Try adding a force to the move instead of a completely new velocity.

Comment: @Catwood Any chance that you can help with providing a little bit of code?

Comment: Sorry, looking at your code in more detail, I don't think this was the issue as you use `rigidbody2D.velocity.y` when creating the new velocity. It must be something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from the up arrow code:

```
(Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began) || (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
```

you're checking if the first touch has just started, if you are holding down a move arrow and you tap up to jump the "jump touch" isn't the first touch and the first touch (for the movement) isn't in it's began phase.

The reason it works with hitting jump and then moving is because the first touch in that case is the jump touch (by coincidence rather than by code).

You don't want to check against the first touch here, you want to check against the touch that is over the up arrow.

(not sure how you'd actually do that, but I can't comment until I get 50 rep :( )

Answer (score 1):

I am also a newbie and was facing this problem few hours ago but I fixed it as I was told to do in an video tutorial so the fix was: Add some drag to your player, in the inspector there is a "Linear Drag" option in your rigidBody component increase it by 0.3(0 is the default value) this really fixed my problem I hope it will also help you(I know it is really late but I just found your question while googling my problem).